# How to access list in a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

As I am completely new to C# I am facing difficulties in implementing this program. I tried this but not getting the desired output. Can anyone help me with this?

Write a program that add new members in the group available.

There are three groups:
1 - Gold
2 - Silver
3 - Platinum.

Get the group input and member name from the user.

Add the particular member to that specified group and display all the member under that group.

Use the Collection concepts to implement.

#### Sample #1

- Input:

  - Group Name :Silver
  - Member Name:

    - Rahul
- Output:

  - Sam
  - Peter
  - Rahul

#### Sample #2

- Input:

  - Group Name: Gold
  - Member Name:

    - Helen
- Output:

  - Tom
  - Harry
  - Helen

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AddNewMember              //Do not change the namespace name
{
    public class Club          //Do not change the class name
    {

        static Dictionary<int, string> groupInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "Gold" }, { 2, "Silver" }, { 3, "Platinum" } };
        static Dictionary<int, List<String>> memberInfo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>() {
                                    { 1, new List<string>(){ "Tom","Harry"} },
                                    { 2,new List<string>(){ "Sam","Peter"} },
                                    { 3,new List<string>(){ "Kim","Robert"} } };

        public static void Main(string[] args)        //Do not change the method signature
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group Name:");
            string group = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Member Name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (group == "Gold")
            {
                if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(1)) { 
                List<string> goldset = new List<string>();
                goldset.Add(name);
                      
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> names in memberInfo)
                    {
                        if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(1)) { 
                            foreach (string value in names.Value) { 
                            Console.WriteLine(value);
                                
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
               

            }
            else if (group == "Silver")
            {
                if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(2))
                {
                    List<string> silverset = new List<string>();
                    silverset.Add(name);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> names in memberInfo)
                    {
                        if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(2))
                        {
                            foreach (string value in names.Value)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(value);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (group == "Platinum")
            {
                if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(3))
                {
                    List<string> platinumset = new List<string>();
                    platinumset.Add(name);
                    List<string> silverset = new List<string>();
                    silverset.Add(name);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> names in memberInfo)
                    {
                        if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(3))
                        {
                            foreach (string value in names.Value)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(value);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this looks like a homework assignment I'll give you a hint. You can access the different lists in your dictionary by their key. `memberInfo[1]` will give you the `List<string>` that contains all your gold members. These are the lists you want to call `Add` on to add a member and use in a `foreach` loop to print all the names.

Comment: @Vignesh Another suggestion is to use `Dictionary<string, int>` to map group names to group ids (instead of the other way around). This will help you a lot during the `memberInfo` lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to slight modification of your code to demonstrate accessing list from a dictionary in context of your program requirement. It is also a slight improvement on your code as it makes a check if group is available and also removes redundant code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AddNewMember              //Do not change the namespace name
{
    public class Club          //Do not change the class name
    {

        static Dictionary<int, string> groupInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "Gold" }, { 2, "Silver" }, { 3, "Platinum" } };
        static Dictionary<int, List<String>> memberInfo = new Dictionary<int, List<String>>() {
                                    { 1, new List<string>(){ "Tom","Harry"} },
                                    { 2,new List<string>(){ "Sam","Peter"} },
                                    { 3,new List<string>(){ "Kim","Robert"} } };

        public static void Main(string[] args)        //Do not change the method signature
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group Name:");
            string group = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Member Name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            KeyValuePair<int,string> searchedGroup = groupInfo.Where(x => x.Value.ToLower() == group.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault();

            if (searchedGroup.Key == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n********** Error: Group not found. **********");
            }
            else
            {
                KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> searchedMemberGroup = memberInfo.Where(x => x.Key == searchedGroup.Key).Single();
                searchedMemberGroup.Value.Add(name);

                Console.WriteLine("******* Group Detail *********");
                Console.WriteLine($"Group Name: {searchedGroup.Value}");
                Console.WriteLine("Member Names:");

                foreach (var item in searchedMemberGroup.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("" + item);
                }
            }            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing memberinfo but not adding that value. You have added a input from user in a list but not adding that name to dictionary variable.

Try this :

```
else if (group == "Silver")
        {
            if (memberInfo.ContainsKey(2))
            {
                List<string> silverset = new List<string>();
                silverset.Add(name);

                var newMemberInfo = memberInfo[2];
                newMemberInfo.Add(name);

                foreach (string value in newMemberInfo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(value);

                }
            }
        }
```